# How to capture request from REST call?

Tags: java, rest, smartystreets

How can I capture the request from a REST call?

I am using this code from SmartyStreets:

https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/blob/master/java/LiveAddressExample.java
(I inserted my auth ID and auth token.)

I tried using the string that is stored in *req*, but that is not correct.

[edit]
Which object does the request live on?

Comment: Have you tried using the console debug mode? `-Djavax.net.debug=all`

Comment: @PatrickJAbareII Trying now.  What should I look for? End of console: main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 179
main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1
main, Exception while waiting for close java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
main, called closeSocket()
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)

Comment: looks like it's not even making a successful connection, so you wouldn't see an XML output

Comment: Would the request be formatted in xml?

Comment: Hmmm.. actually not 100% sure, you'd see something more than a SocketException, that's for sure. Once the SocketException is handled, you should see something. That debug statement logs all java.net transactions.

Comment: The request is going to be generated by the implementation of the URLConnection that is returned by URL.openConnection().  Try wandering through the code on grepcode to find where it is created.  In any case, it seems unlikely that you can access the request.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see I can see in your example, you are opening a new URL connection, in this way, I think that aren't a complete "Request Object" that you can recover (that means a object which contains target, headers and content of message, etc), since you are managing by separate the connection, the headers and the content message, each of these, components of the request, you have it by separate, I have one question about what is the info you need that is not already available in your code?

Comment: The customer support guys at SmartyStreets wanted the request that I am sending, so I'm trying to somehow capture that request.  But based on your comment it sounds like the request does not exist.

Comment: I think, if you send to them the message (the content in req variable) and the headers that you are setting, and the url fos connection, that would be enough.